# NLTK: Naive Bayes - where/how to add in ngrams?

Tags: python, nlp, classification, nltk, sentiment-analysis

I am doing a classification task on tweets (3 labels= pos, neg, neutral), for which I'm using Naive Bayes in NLTK. I'd like to add in ngrams (bigrams) as well. I have tried adding them to the code, but I don't seem to get where to fit them right in. At the moment it seems as if I'm "breaking" the code, no matter where I add in the bigrams. Could anybody please help me out, or redirect me to a tutorial?

My code for unigrams follows. If you need any information on how the datasets look, I'd be happy to provide it.

```
import nltk
import csv
import random 
import nltk.classify.util, nltk.metrics
import codecs
import re, math, collections, itertools
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.classify import NaiveBayesClassifier
from nltk.probability import FreqDist, ConditionalFreqDist 
from nltk.util import ngrams
from nltk import bigrams
from nltk.metrics import BigramAssocMeasures
from nltk.collocations import BigramCollocationFinder
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.stem.snowball import SnowballStemmer
from nltk.tokenize import WordPunctTokenizer

tokenizer = WordPunctTokenizer()
stemmer = SnowballStemmer("english", ignore_stopwords = True)
stopset = set(stopwords.words('english'))

stopset.add('username')
stopset.add('url')
stopset.add('percentage')
stopset.add('number')
stopset.add('at_user')
stopset.add('AT_USER')
stopset.add('URL')
stopset.add('percentagenumber')


inpTweets = []
##with open('sanders.csv', 'r', 'utf-8') as f:   #input sanders    
##    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter = ';')    
##    for row in reader: 
##        inpTweets.append((row))
reader = codecs.open('...sanders.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8-sig') #input classified tweets
for line in reader:
    line = line.rstrip()
    row = line.split(';')
    inpTweets.append((row))    

def processTweet(tweet):
    tweet = tweet.lower()
    tweet = re.sub('((www\.[^\s]+)|(https?://[^\s]+))','URL',tweet)
    tweet = re.sub('@[^\s]+','AT_USER',tweet)
    tweet = re.sub('[\s]+', ' ', tweet)
    tweet = re.sub(r'#([^\s]+)', r'\1', tweet)
    tweet = tweet.strip('\'"')
    return tweet

def replaceTwoOrMore(s):
    #look for 2 or more repetitions of character and replace with the character itself
    pattern = re.compile(r"(.)\1{1,}", re.DOTALL)
    return pattern.sub(r"\1\1", s)


def preprocessing(doc): 
    tokens = tokenizer.tokenize(doc)
    bla = []
    for x in tokens:
        if len(x)>2:
            if x not in stopset:
                val = re.search(r"^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$", x)
                if val is not None:
                    x = replaceTwoOrMore(x)
                    x = processTweet(x)
                    x = x.strip('\'"?,.')
                    x = stemmer.stem(x).lower()
                    bla.append(x)
    return bla

xyz = []

for lijn in inpTweets:
    xyz.append((preprocessing (lijn[0]),lijn[1]))
random.shuffle(xyz)

featureList = []
k = 0
while k in range (0, len(xyz)):
    featureList.extend(xyz[k][0])
    k = k + 1

fd = nltk.FreqDist(featureList)
featureList = list(fd.keys())[2000:]

def document_features(doc):    
    features = {}
    document_words = set(doc)
    for word in featureList:
        features['contains(%s)' % word] = (word in document_words)
    return features


featuresets =  nltk.classify.util.apply_features(document_features, xyz)

training_set, test_set = featuresets[2000:], featuresets[:2000]

classifier = nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier.train(training_set)
```

Comment: how does `sanders.csv` look like? can you give a snippet of the data?

Comment: @alvas the sanders file, when I load it into Python (i.e. when I load it into inpTweets) is a list of lists that looks like this: [['tweet1','sentiment1'],['tweet2','sentiment2']...]. For example: [['in honor of steve jobs username ripsteve url', 'neutral'],['when is username gonna update the fact that i cant see emoji on twitter for mac',
  'neutral']]. The three labels used in the Sanders set are pos, neg and neutral

Answer (score 0):

Your code uses the 2000 most common words as the classification features. Just select the bigrams you want to use, and convert them to features in `document_features()`. A feature like `"contains (the dog)"` will work just like `"contains (dog)"`.

Answer (score -1):

An interesting approach is using a [sequential backoff tagger](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/tag/sequential.html), which allows you to chain taggers together: in this way you could train a n-gram tagger and a Naive Bayes and chain them togheter.

Comment: I don't think the classifier ever backs off-- why would it?

Comment: From the comment of the link I posted: "If a tagger is unable to
determine a tag for the specified token, then its backoff tagger is
consulted instead."

Comment: You're still talking about taggers; the question is about classifiers.